# rename column as file name - multiple csv files R

Tags: r, csv

I have 200 csv files with names "a.csv", "b.csv", "c.csv" etc..

In each csv file, there are two columns:  "type" and "abundance". I'd like to change the name of the *abundance* column in each csv file to "a_abundance","b_abundance" etc. to match the file name, and then save the csv file with the new column names.

So far I have the following, but it doesn't work.

```
filenames<- list.files(pattern = ".csv")

all_files <- lapply (filenames, function (x) {
  file <- read.csv (x) 
  name= sub(".*", "", x) 
  
  colnames(file) <- paste (colnames(file), name, sep ='_') 
  
 return(file)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```r
all_files <- lapply(setNames(nm=filenames), function(fn) {
  dat <- read.csv(fn)
  ind <- colnames(dat) == "abundance"
  if (any(ind)) {
    colnames(dat)[ind] <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(fn)), "_abundance")
  }
  dat
})
```

The above will read the data and change the one column name. (You said just one column, but your code is changing all columns ... I'll stick with just the one named `"abundance"`.)

From here, you can rewrite with *one* from:

```r
Map(write.csv, all_files, names(all_files))
## or ##
for (nm in names(all_files)) write.csv(all_files[[nm]], nm)
```

---

FYI, this could be done a *lot faster* on the command-line (bash shell or similar, as long as `sed` is available) with something like:

```sh
for fn in $(ls *.csv) ; do
  BN=$(basename "$fn" .csv)
  sed -i -E "1{s/abundance/${BN}_abundance/}" "$fn"
done
```

Walk-through:

- For `BN`, the `basename` removes any leading directory component, and the trailing `.csv` removes that extension from the filename; this should translate `./a.csv` to `a`.
- For `sed`:

  - `-i` make the modification *in-place* on the file; **note**, this does not store a backup of the original file; if you use instead `-i.bak` then it will back up the file before modifying it, perhaps safer the first time you try this, then you can remove the `*.bak` files
  - `-E` is an extended-expression thing; you should be able to get by with `-e` as well, it's just habit for me
  - `1` means to only apply this rule on the first line of the file
  - `s/from/to/` translates text from the `from` pattern to the `to` pattern, in this case prepending `${BN}_` (braces are a little defensive in bash envvar usage)